# select time series data by month

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have time series data that appears like below:

```
data

          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      
1960 -10.3000  -7.1000   2.9000  18.0000  18.9000  29.5000  31.4000  28.0000  20.7000  
1961  -1.8000  -4.2000   4.0000  13.2000  22.0000  23.4000  24.0000  23.4000  17.3000  
1962 -12.1000  -3.1000  -0.1000   9.5000  22.9000  24.4000  26.4000  30.0000  21.2000  
1963  -2.9000  -5.9000   5.4000   9.3000  21.0000  25.3000  27.9000  24.6000  21.4000  
1964  -2.8000  -7.4000   2.2000   9.1000  17.6000  25.3000  25.1000  25.3000  18.0000  
1965  -9.5000   1.0000   6.3000  14.3000  18.3000  24.7000  28.4000  26.7000  21.9000  
1966  -5.4000  -2.7000   6.6000  14.3000  17.7000  24.2000  26.2000  25.3000  20.5000   
1967  -8.1000  -0.6000   3.0000  13.8000  23.2000  23.8000  27.6000  24.3000  20.4000
```

I want to plot the data on monthly scale, for example, I want to plot data of January month from 1960-1967. I tried using `zoo` function but it does not work. The problem is that even after installing `zoo` package, the `zoo` function seems to be unrecognized by the system. The error message looks like this:

```
> install.packages("zoo")
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/skhanal2.RUSSELL/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/zoo_1.7-9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 868277 bytes (847 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 847 Kb
package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘zoo’

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\skhanal2.RUSSELL\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCSHWVD\downloaded_packages
> test<-zoo(data,by="month")
**Error: could not find function "zoo"**
```

Has anyone tried to plot time series data by month?If so, I would appreciate if someone could help me find the solution. Also, can anyone suggest what is the problem in `zoo` function? I am using R version 2.15.2 and I am using Windows 7 in 32 bit machine.  Thanks!

Comment: In the future if you use dput() it will be easier for others to work with your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't enough to install the package.  You also have to load it into memory using the `library()` command, e.g. `library(zoo)`.  Once you get the zoo package loaded correctly...

```
 test<-zoo(data,order.by=sort(data$year))
 plot(test)
 #or
 plot(test[,c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep")])
```

Comment: Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘zoo’ - doesn't look promising.  You might shutdown R and try reinstalling.  Failing that if you go to the library folder off of the root of where R is installed you might manually delete the zoo folder, restart R and try installing again.

Comment: However, it seems pretty clear that your problem at this point isn't statistical, it is technical.  (Although your call to zoo also looks flawed).

Comment: Thanks. I did work after restarting the R software. Do you have any idea about filtering data by month in the time-series?

Comment: I edited my answer, the code above should "plot the data on monthly scale" as you requested.

Comment: Sorry if I am being very naive but I could not run the code you suggested:
test<-zoo(data,order.by=sort(data$year))

As the data is in time series format, there is no column such as year. My data appears as:
structure(c(-10.3, -7.1, 2.9, 18, 18.9, 29.5, 31.4, 28, 20.7, 
17.9, 5.9, -2.4, -1.8, -4.2, 4, 13.2, 22, 23.4, 24, 23.4, 17.3, 
13, 3.4, -7), .Tsp = c(1960, 1961.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I guess I created year from the rownames in your example dataset.  I assume you are showing me the structure of what is in test.  Go back to data... and before you run `test<-zoo(data,order.by=sort(data$year))` run `data$year <- rownames(data)` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Sami, Seems you have a `ts` series. Try `monthplot(tser)` where `tser` is your series.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I did not quite follow the manual on monthplot in terms of what is being plotted.  Are those trend lines across years for each of the months?

Comment: @Sami, Try `tser2 <- ts(1:120, freq = 12); moonthplot(tser2)` to clarify it for yourself.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I got the solution to my problem. I should mainly subset the data for the month I want to plot the data. The code looks like this: Aug<-subset(data, cycle(data)==8); plot(Aug)

Comment: @Samikhanal: Sure that will work, but then you aren't really using the information from the time series and you've lost the relationship between your data and the year it was collected.